# how to get SoapClient to fail more gracefully?

Tags: php, error-handling, soap-client

I'm making a call to an external service as per their API:

```
            $client = new SoapClient($this->apiUrl, array(
            'trace' => 1,
            'exceptions' => 1,
            'encoding' => 'UTF-8'
        ));
```

And it works just fine... but then I tested it deliberately screwing up apiUrl to an invalid address, and I was shocked to see a server 500 error and this in my logs:

```
[09-Nov-2015 22:10:07 MST] PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://fakeaddress.com/wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://fakeaddress.com/wsdl"
in /home/account/public_html/test/test.php on line 171
[09-Nov-2015 22:10:08 MST] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://fakeaddress.com/wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://fakeaddress.com/wsdl"
in /home/account/public_html/test/test.php:171
```

That's not good.  If that site is down for whatever reason, I need to handle the error, not just show the user a 500.  How can I do that?

I read several notes about a bug/issue when xdebug is enabled.  I checked, it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out.  This resolved it for me:

```
        try {
            $client = @new SoapClient($this->apiUrl, array(
                'trace' => 1,
                'exceptions' => 1,
                'encoding' => 'UTF-8'
            ));
        } catch (SoapFault $E) {

            //CODE TO RUN IF ERROR OCCURS GOES HERE

        }
```

While I can't say *why* wrapping in try/catch works, it does.  I believe this really is a bug, although php insists it isn't (using this try/catch as proof) but with 'exceptions' set to 1 it should do just that... throw an exception, not a fatal.  There's just no way a network error should ever be considered fatal from php's perspective.  But I guess that's just my opinion